# Views argument to match single date with date range field

Tags: 7, datetime, views

My content type has a date field with an end date. So an example node has a date range, say from 2011-01-01 to 2011-01-30.

In my view, I want to add an argument/contextual filter that shows any nodes covering a specific day. So if the argument value is 2011-01-15, the node shows (it falls within its range). If the argument value is 2011-02-01, the node doesn't show.

In the Date (node) argument settings, I've played around with selecting both from and to date fields and the OR/AND settings, but can't find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug, please see [Multi-day events don't show up on day view of spanned days](http://drupal.org/node/1147620#comment-4657576).

Comment: Thanks - I think I see what you mean. That discussion is about calendar views (I'm using a list view) but it seems that the argument is flawed, regardless of display used in the view. Just so I'm clear... in the argument settings it says "Select one or more date fields to filter with this argument. Do not select both the 'From date' and 'To date' for date fields, only one of them is needed." But whatever field you select (from or to) it doesn't take the whole date span into account?

Comment: Correct. The bug was discovered because of a calendar view, but the query is the same.